# Parse yaml in python, where upper level does not have a definite name

Tags: python, yaml

i have the following test.yaml file

```
123:
  am: null
  cm:
    host: host1
    password: admin1234
    port: 443
    scheme: https
    username: admin
  dm:
    name: 123
    secret: abc
345:
  am: null
  cm:
    host: host2
    password: admin1234
    port: 443
    scheme: https
    username: admin
  dm:
    name: 123
    secret: abc
```

i have the following function which parses the yaml file

```
import yaml
from typing import Optional, Dict, Any, cast


def read_yaml(path: str) -> Optional[Dict[str, Any]]:
    yaml_path = '{}/test.yaml'.format(path)
    with open(yaml_path, 'r') as res:
        try:
            yaml_parsed = cast(Dict[str, Any], yaml.safe_load(res))
        except yaml.YAMLError as e:
            logging.error(f"yaml parsing failed. Error: {e}")
            return None
        else:
            logging.info("yaml parsed succesfully.")
            return yaml_parsed
```

call and output of the function:

```
res = read_yaml(path)
print(res)
```

```
{123: {'am': None, 'cm': {'host': 'host1', 'password': 'admin1234', 'port': 443, 'scheme': 'https', 'username': 'admin'}, 'dm': {'name': 123, 'secret': 'abc'}}, 345: {'am': None, 'cm': {'host': 'host2', 'password': 'admin1234', 'port': 443, 'scheme': 'https', 'username': 'admin'}, 'dm': {'name': 123, 'secret': 'abc'}}}
```

I need to iterate thru this yaml and use the nested values (host, username, password)
My main problem is that on the top level i dont have a column name just values (123, 345 in the provided example)

How i can take out these information from the above yaml?
so i need host,username,password for both entries so i can iterate thru the result and use those values for an API call.

upd:
i need something like this: (or any other solution where i can iterate and use those values. If i have a list of lists then i can solve that part, probably i could use the original format for that without any transformation, but my limited python knowledge is not enough for that)

```
[[host:host1 , username: admin, password: admin1234],[host:host2 , username: admin, password: admin1234]]
```

upd2:
need something like this in pseudo code and use values from the yaml:

```
for i in mydict
    some_func(host,username,password)
```

thanks

Comment: `res` isn't "a YAML". YAML is a text format. As soon as you called `yaml.safe_load`, you were done working with YAML. You now have an ordinary Python `dict`.

Comment: What do you mean by *I don't have a column name just values*? *column* isn't a YAML term. What do you mean by *take out these information*? Do you want to transform the YAML into having a sequence instead of a mapping on top level? If you just want to iterate over the values, why is having the `123` / `345` a problem, why can't you just ignore them when iterating over the dict?

Comment: sorry for the bad terms i use, but i new to python world. i need something like:
({host:host1 , username: admin, password: admin1234},{host:host2 , username: admin, password: admin1234}) or in any format i can use for iteration later on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that every item in the YAML file has a `cm` key and each of them has all three of the fields you're looking for, this will unpack stuff into a list of dictionaries you can use:

```
keys = ['host', 'username', 'password']
hosts = [{key: item['cm'][key] for key in keys} for item in res.values()]
```

`hosts` is now as follows:

```
[{'host': 'host1', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'admin1234'},
 {'host': 'host2', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'admin1234'}]
```

However, you might be able to get by with just extracting the values you want when you run your for loop:

```
for item in res.values()
    cm = item['cm']
    some_func(cm['host'], cm['username'], cm['password'])
```

Perhaps the real key insight here is the existence of the [`values`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) method in dict objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another mean, using a simple recursive function that will etirate through the dict searching for the keyword:

```
from typing import Dict
def deep_search_dico(that_dico, keyword, results):
    the_results = results.copy()
    for name, el in that_dico.items():
        if name == keyword:
            return el.copy()
        elif isinstance(el,dict):
            results.append(deep_search_dico(el, keyword, results))
    return results


the_dico = {123: {'am': None, 'cm': {'host': 'host1', 'password': 'admin1234', 'port': 443, 'scheme': 'https', 'username': 'admin'}, 'dm': {'name': 123, 'secret': 'abc'}}, 345: {'am': None, 'cm': {'host': 'host2', 'password': 'admin1234', 'port': 443, 'scheme': 'https', 'username': 'admin'}, 'dm': {'name': 123, 'secret': 'abc'}}}

print(deep_search_dico(the_dico, "cm", []))
```